# Using .htaccess to Rewrite URLs with ID

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

If I have a URL `http://www.example.com/page.php?id=1` is it possible for me to re-write that to `http://www.example.com/m _ (ANY TITLE) _ (ID)`?

Comment: Sure it is, here's a quick'n'dirty way: `RewriteRule _([0-9]+)$  page.php?id=$1  [L]`

Comment: Thank you .. Works well but I want to be a m_ necessary 
example /m_contact_7

Comment: If the title can not contain any underscores, use this rule: `RewriteRule ^m_([^_]+)_([0-9]+)$ page.php?id=$2 [L]`

Comment: @TomKnapen: Why don’t you provide this as an answer? So this question can be checkmarked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the title can not contain any underscores, use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^m_([^_]+)_([0-9]+)$ page.php?id=$2 [L]
```